# Set promiscuous port for upstream LACP trunk on Cisco 2960X

Tags: cisco-ios, ieee-802.1ax, private-vlan

I have a series of clients who are looking into a intra-VLAN isolation scheme to satisfy a DDQ request.

I was looking into deploying private VLANs for all client device / voice VLANs to satisfy this requirement. However, it appears that our northward link to our firewall is a LACP bundle, and private VLANs are not supported for LACP. Until I [found a page that implied that other switch models do support a promiscuous port for LACP.](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst9400/software/release/17-3/configuration_guide/vlan/b_173_vlan_9400_cg/configuring_private_vlans.html) Most of our devices are the Cisco 2960X, and I am hoping the [document I am looking at](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960x/software/15-2_7_e/configuration_guide/b_1527e_consolidated_2960x_cg/m_vlan_private_cg_2960-xr.html?bookSearch=true) is just out of date.

I do see this is a different model, and a much newer version of IOS. However, I cant find any confirmation of what changed.

Is this a firmware limitation, a hardware limitation, or me reading the Cisco documentation incorrectly?

Comment: You mean *intra*-VLAN isolation, don't you? VLANs are each separated anyway. Usually you can use the upstream port (or LAG) without isolation, but I'm not sure about a 2960X. Why don't you test this in a lab?

Comment: Yes, I meant intra-VLAN isolation. My bad. Will correct. 

I have a lab and the command is missing. Thats why I was curious on what the cause of the issue.